# Joda money: How to convert formatted string back to monetary value (independent of locale)

Tags: java, currency-formatting, money-format, joda-money

Assume we have the amount $12345.67

This can be converted into a Monetary value using joda money library with:

```
Money parsed = Money.parse("USD 12345.67");

//Now to display the amount according to the users locale we use:
MoneyFormatter mf =  MoneyFormatterBuilder().appendAmountLocalized().toFormatter();
String localeString = mf.withLocale(Locale.getDefault()).print(parsed);

//Now assume the user is for example in Europe so the locale string would be 12.345,46
//Now assume he changes the amount inside a textfield to 12.345,47
Money changed = /*parse 12.345,47 (USD)*/
```

The question is how can I parse the localized String back to the monetary value (pay attention to the grouping digit which is a dot and the fraction digit with is a comma). This also has to work with every money value and every string that comes out from the above formatter.

`Money.parse()` only works on this regex which does not fulfill the requirements `[+-]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Got it. You can use the MoneyFormatter vice versa. Documentation was just a bit unclear

```
MoneyFormatter mf =  MoneyFormatterBuilder().appendAmountLocalized().toFormatter()
MoneyParseContext parsed = mf.withLocale(Locale.getDefault()).parse(amount,0);
parsed.setCurrency(currency);
Money money = Money.of(parsed.toBigMoney());
```